# Is it possible to use parameterized queries in influxdb via nodejs driver?

Tags: node.js, influxdb

Consider the scenario: a client app sends me the name of the table I need to get data from and additional information such as date range. How can one construct such queries safely? I use nodejs as my backend and influxdb as data store.

Comment: What do you mean by "safely"?

Comment: @pootzko In this scenarion a client can send something like "drop database" instead of table name. How to avoid that?

Comment: You should take care of that on the app-level IMO. Influx provides a bit of security but I think it's not as fine grained as one might like.

Comment: @pootzko ok, thank you for your reply